# Flutter/RiverPod - zap all providers with log out?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

With RiverPod, is there a way to reset/zap all providers as part of a user log out process?

Comment: Have a provider that updates on login change (logout, login as different user), and have every provider that wants to be reset on those events simply ref.watch(thatProvider) in your build or callback.  You don't even have to use the value.

Comment: I've ended up doing just that, but that has entailed injecting extra cost into half a dozen different providers

Answer (score 2):

In general, your architecture should be arranged in such a way that you don't have to do it. When you leave any screen, all providers can be reset via `ref.invalidate(provider)`, and co-dependent providers (via `ref.watch`) will also be reset.

Also, you can try to reset the status of the entire container:

```dart
final container = ProviderContainer();

container.dispose()
```